# operation time connecting openshift in java

Tags: java, ssh, openshift, jsch, openshift-cartridge

I want to connect to my mysql database cartridge in openshift through java.

So I create a ssl connection using jsch in my java file. When I run it, give me error operation timed out. Can any one help me out with this. My java code is :

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

JSch jsc = new JSch();
jsc.addIdentity("/Users/Adhirajchoudhary/.ssh/id_rsa1");
session=jsc.getSession(sshUserName, sshHostName, 3306);
session.setPassword(sshPassword);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
System.out.println("Connected");
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the same host/port/user/pass using any GUI SSH/SFTP client from the same host?

Comment: I tried connecting through the mysql workbench. It successfully connceted

Comment: So why are you trying to connect with SSH? (Does the workbench connect with SSH?) Also note that you confuse SSL and SSH. Also the answer by @corey112358 has a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we are missing some key information in the code you provided, and it also looks like you are trying to ssh to port 3306? That's not going to work.  You would have to ssh to port 22, then try to create a tunnel over that connection.  You could also try using the OpenShift Java Client and have it setup a port forward for you to use.